# How do I simplify nested flatmaps in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this input validation code:

```
let res = {};

res.validate = function (body) {

  return toValid(!!body, `Empty body`)
    .flatMap(_ =>
      toValid(typeof body.name === 'string', 'Name must be a string')
        .flatMap(_ =>
          toValid(typeof body.handle === 'string', 'Handle must be a string')
            .flatMap(_ =>
              toValid(body.handle.match(/[a-z|0-9]*/), 'Handle must contain lowercase letters and numbers')
              )
        )
    );

};
```

I want to get rid of nested flatmaps like a do notation.

Maybe I want a function to convert this into :

```
  [() => toValid(!!body, `Empty body`),
   () => toValid(typeof body.name === 'string', 'Name must be a string')
   () => toValid(typeof body.handle === 'string', 'Handle must be a string'),
   () => toValid(body.handle.match(/[a-z|0-9]*/), 'Handle must contain lowercase letters and numbers')
  ];
```

or something better.

Here's to `toValid` function:

```
const toValid = function (value, _invalid) {
  return value ? new Validation(null, value) :
new Validation(_invalid);
};


function Validation(invalid, valid) {
  this.invalid = invalid;
  this.valid = valid;

  this.flatMap = (fvalid, finvalid = _ => new Validation(_)) => {
      return this.valid ? fvalid(this.valid) :
      finvalid(this.invalid);
  };

}
```

Comment: What is the `toValid` function?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem--is this a normal way to do validation in the first place? The fact that you've run into this awkward piece of code indicates fundamental design problems. If you provide more context, there is likely a better solution that someone can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks quite over-engineered - it's unnecessarily difficult to cognitively parse at a glance. Consider using `if` statements instead, something like:

```
res.validate = function (body) {
  if (!body) return 'Empty body';
  if (typeof body.name !== 'string') return 'Name must be a string';
  if (typeof body.handle !== 'string') return 'Handle must be a string';
  if (!body.handle.match(/[a-z|0-9]*/)) return 'Handle must contain lowercase letters and numbers');
};
```

If you wanted to use an array:

```
res.validate = function (body) {
  const validators = [
    [body, 'Empty body'],
    [body.name === 'string', 'Name must be a string'],
    [typeof body.handle === 'string', 'Handl emust be a string'],
    [body.handle.match(/[a-z|0-9]*/), 'Handle must contain lowercase letters and numbers']
  ];
  const failedValidator = validators.find(v => !v[0]);
  if (failedValidator) return failedValidator[1];
};
```

But there's another issue - your regex will not function properly. It will match *any* input string, because the only token is repeated with a `*` - 0 or more times.

If you want to make sure the input only contains letters and numbers, do:

```
.match(/^[a-z\d]+$/i)
```

(one or more case-insensitive alphabetical or digit characters, spanning from the beginning of the string to the end)